# In Pytest , How to update url in non test file from command line

Tags: python, pytest, web-api-testing

I am exploring pytest for my project needs, and it seems very handy so far, but now I am struggling at one point where I want to update the URL in my helper methods from command line options .We have different environments dev, qa and pre-prod and for each environment we have different URL.

one approach which I am using now is I am passing the name of the env from command line and updating the value of url accordingly in a fixture in conftest.py

This fixture I am using in my tests and then pass the url to helpers.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5i0h.png)

## Code with fixture

```
##############  conftest.py    ##############
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
        parser.addoption("--env_name", action="store", default="dev", help="Enter env name  as dev or qa")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session",autouse=True)
def env_config(request):
        env_name = request.config.getoption("--env_name")
        if env_name == "dev":
            return 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories'
        elif env_name == "qa":
            return 'https://bing.com'
        else:
            return 'https://www.bing.com'


##############   api_helper.py  ##############
import requests 

def search(search_engine_url, query_string):
   resp = requests.get(url=search_engine_url, params={'q': query_string})
   return resp


##############   test_search1.py    ##############   
from helpers import api_helper

def test_1(env_config):
    BASE_URL = env_config
    resp = api_helper.search(BASE_URL,"what is pytest")
    print resp

def test_2(env_config):
    BASE_URL = env_config
    resp = api_helper.search(BASE_URL,"Learn pytest")
    print resp
```

## Code with BASE_URL

```
############## config.py ##############################
BASE_URL = ''
set_base_url(env_name):
    global BASE_URL
    if env_name == "dev":
        BASE_URL ='https://api.github.com/search/repositories'
    elif env_name == "qa":
        BASE_URL ='https://bing.com'
    else:
        BASE_URL ='https://www.bing.com'


##############  conftest.py    ##############

import pytest
import config


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--env_name", action="store", default="dev", help="Enter env name  as dev or qa")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session",autouse=True)
def env_config(request):
    env_name = request.config.getoption("--env_name")
    config.set_base_url(env_name)

##############   api_helper.py  ##############
import requests 
import config

 # Below loads before command line arguments and gives BASE_URL value =''
 search_engine_url = config.BASE_URL  
 def search(search_engine_url, query_string):
       resp = requests.get(url=search_engine_url, params={'q': query_string})
       return resp

##############   test_search1.py    ##############   
from helpers import api_helper

def test_1(env_config):
    resp = api_helper.search(BASE_URL,"what is pytest")
    print resp

def test_2(env_config):
   resp = api_helper.search(BASE_URL,"Learn pytest")
   print resp
```

Now I want to know if we have any other approach by which I can update the URL in api_helper module, so that I don't need to pass it with every test case.

Thank you!!

Comment: You could make `BASE_URL` a global variable, set it in the fixture, and set the fixture to `autouse=True`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that as well, but when we execute things helper module get invoke before anything, as we are using it in our tests and then reference of BASE_URL gives the exception.Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: You mean `BASE_URL` is used before it is initialized? Maybe you can update your question to show what you have tried - difficult to say otherwise.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen please let me know if approach is ok or not? If possible could you please share the better way of doing it. Thank you for investing your time and helping me out.

Comment: I think this is perfectly ok. You either have to pass the fixture as in your first approach, or save the url somewhere globally (or in a class variable, if you would use test classes). Note that you left the `env_config` variable in your tests in the second approach, probably accidentally - you don't need it.